# On-Behalf-Of Azure Mobile backend - MS Graph

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services, microsoft-graph-api

Another attempt to ask a different question surrounding my month long problem:

I'm now trying to initiate the "On-Behalf-Of" flow to get a MS Graph token when users login with a Microsoft Account. As documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of

On the client, users log in with a server-flow:

```
var user = await MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);
```

On the .NET backend, I am trying to retrieve the MS Graph token:

```
string clientId = "id-shown-in-app-registration-portal";
string clientSecret = "secret-shown-in-app-registration-portal";
IEnumerable<string> msIdTokenOut = null;
Request.Headers.TryGetValues("x-ms-token-microsoftaccount-access-token", out msIdTokenOut);
string msIdToken = msIdTokenOut.FirstOrDefault();
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0");
UserAssertion assertion = new UserAssertion(msIdToken);
ClientCredential cred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", cred, assertion);
```

I get the following error:
aadsts50027: invalid jwt token. token format not valid.

I've tried every possible combination, from using server-flow to login, using MSAL for client-flow (which doesn't authenticate against App Services with the retrieved token). This has been driving me crazy for over a month. I can't believe how many hoops I have jumped through to get 2 Microsoft products working together. If anyone can steer me towards a solution I would be beyond grateful.

Comment: As far as I know,  live sdk token couldn't used in the oauth on behalf of now. I have also create both client-flow and server-flow to login to test it. I find we couldn't use the return token to oauth on behalf. I suggest you could add [feedback](http://feedback.azure.com) to azure team to include this feature.

Comment: Thank you, I will submit feedback. For now, do you have any suggestion on how I can include MS Graph access in my Azure Mobile backend? Is there any flow that works?

Comment: There is a workaround. I suggest you could try to enable custom auth not using easy auth by using the MSAL access token in the mobile backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround, I suggest you could enable the mobile server custom authentication by using MSAL returned access token.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

Firstly, you could create a login page which will use MSAL login with the microsoft account. It will return the access token.

Then you could send the request with the access token to the mobile service backend to ask for authentication.

Notice: The logic in the backend which used to check the access token is right, you need achieve by yourself. You could decode the access jwt token to get the aud value. If this value is as same as the client id that means the user have the permission to access mobile backend data.

Then you could use jwt token to get the user information from graph api. After get the user information, you could set the user information value to claims to generate the auth token(using this method AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken[Add Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Login NuGet package]). By using this token the mobile client user could access the mobile backend.

The access token like this:

[image]

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/) to know how to enable custom auth in mobile backend.